# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed problem with (Range(ActiveCell).Offset(-10, 1).Select)

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to create a vba code for excel that hides a column if cells are empty for 10 progressive cells before moving to the next column, starting with cell m9. However, I am having trouble solving this error message. I am new to VBA, so I'm unsure how to proceed. Any help would much be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub HideColumns()
' Assumed if empty cell for 10 progressive cells in the same column, then is empty
' for the entirety of the test

' Our tests start at cell M9, so we will use a conditional loop to use the offset
' method on the range object from there
    StartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("M9").Select
    For i = 1 To 10
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then
            Range(ActiveCell).Offset(i).Select
        ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = False Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    If i = 10 Then
            HiddenColoumn = ActiveCell.Column
            Columns("HiddenColoumn:HiddenColoumn").Select
            Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' now the column is hidden as there is no data for 10 progressive cells
            Range(ActiveCell).Offset(-10, 1).Select
            i = 1 ' reset counter for next loop
    ElseIf i <> 10 Then
            Range(ActiveCell).Offset(-10, 1).Select
            i = 1 ' reset counter for next loop
    End If
```

Comment: If i=10, then offsetting -10 would be zero, which doesn’t exist

Comment: Similar problem would present for the `ElseIf` as if `i=<10` you would be offsetting to a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't select anything. You can address any cell or range just by specifying its address.
Second: The task isn't to check if the first 10 cells are blank but whether there are 10 consecutive blank cells in the column. What about if M9:M10 and M16 have values but all other cells are blank? Then it would be important to know how many rows there are in the sheet because by looking at only one column you can't know if the 10 cells are blank (within the sheet) or not blank (below the sheet).

So, you arrive at a different coding strategy.

```
Sub HideColumns()
    ' 257
    ' Assumed if empty cell for 10 progressive cells in the same column, then is empty
    ' for the entirety of the test
    
    Dim Blank           As Integer              ' count blank cells
    Dim Cl              As Long                 ' last used column in the sheet
    Dim Rl              As Long                 ' last used row in the sheet
    Dim C               As Long                 ' loop counter: columns
    Dim R               As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")                   ' better (meaning safer!) than 'ActiveSheet'
        With .UsedRange
            Cl = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
            Rl = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1
        End With
        
        ' Our tests start at cell M9,
        For C = .Columns("M").Column To Cl
            Blank = 0
            For R = 9 To Rl
                If .Cells(R, C).Value = "" Then
                    Blank = Blank + 1
                    If Blank > 9 Then Exit For
                Else
                    Blank = 0
                End If
            Next R
            .Columns(C).Hidden = (Blank = 10)
        Next C
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I wanted to exit the loop once it reaches column AB, would I use a conditional statement to break the loop?

Comment: You could do that or you could simply set `Cl = 28` or `Cl =  WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns.Count + .Column - 1, 28)`.